# Docker container can't go online

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I've been using Docker for a while, but until now it was exclusively in a way that we would create containers from VMs.

We are not using VMs anymore so there is no need now to make that steps and I was trying to create the container directly.

Therefore, I tried with getting the image by

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

which worked fine, I was able to run a container based on that image. However, I couldn't go online from within that container.

Then I went to hunt down a better suited Dockerfile. [This was](https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile) the best I could find, so I just changed 14.04 to latest and went on. The same result - no internet connection, whereas all the other containers created with the VM step do go online without problems. I raised the issue at the github repo, only to realize that the last update to the repo happened six years ago...

Can anyone tell me the obvious thing I am missing?

Comment: What do you mean by _couldn't go online from within container_? I'm on Fedora 31 (ergo no VM) and when I do `docker container run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04` I'm able to _go online_ (use `apt update`, `apt install`, `curl`, etc.).

Comment: I mean I can't use apt install.

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: It's Ubuntu as well

Comment: Well, I cannot help you if I cannot reproduce it. Maybe someone else has a solution.

Comment: Understandable, thanks for trying

Comment: But, what might be useful for others is if you describe your whole process: what commands do you use, how do you determine your container is offline, etc.